# Slide Toggle a table that is loaded dynamically via load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, slidetoggle

I'm loading a table into my page via the load() method.

The first row of the table is click-able and when clicked must toggle the rest of the table.  The code I am using is below:

```
    $('.collapsable tr:first').live('click', function() {
    $('.collapsable tr:first').nextAll().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

I want the table to hide when the page is loaded.  I have tried using:
     $('.collapsable tr:first').live('load', function() {
but with no luck.

Also tried just putting this:
     $('.collapsable tr:first').nextAll().slideToggle("fast"); into the document.ready function but it also does nothing.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may be help you.

Use .click instead of using .live :

```
$('.collapsable tr:first').click(function() {

    $('.collapsable tr:first').nextAll().slideToggle("Show");

});
```

Comment: Sorry I tried this first and it didn't work. The PHP code that builds the table is on another PHP page that is loaded via jQuery load().